# Approach to follow for undo all changes been done in desktop.ini and also on uninstall of C#.NET application

Tags: c#, .net, database, setup-project, desktop.ini

I have my software been developed in .net in C# and i am modifying desktop.ini file from that software. I am successfully been able to update desktop.ini. But i have one question like what approach should i follow to keep information of desktop.ini which was there previously like should i store information in database or something like that?

And i wanted to reupdate my information of desktop.ini, i.e. information which was stored previously on uninstallation of my software.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me what approach should we follow for this.

Thanks
Dharmen

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of ini files, the answer is to use a tool that supports the standard Windows Installer method of managing ini file content - the IniFile table and the WriteIniValues and RemoveIniValues standard actions, then you don't need to do anything. VS setup projects don't support this.

To code it yourself you'd just need to remember what sections and values you added, then remove them at uninstall time with an uninstall custom action. That's basically a development question about where to store the values so you can retrieve them to take out of the ini file at uninstall time. I don't know if that's much of an answer, but it's basically about coding a scheme to remember what you added or removed and then restoring those section values at uninstall time.

You should also have a rollback custom action to remove them in case the install runs your custom action to alter the ini file and then fails.